# How to convert an hg repo to a git repo on OS X?

Tags: git, mercurial

Yes, I know about hg-fast-export.sh
[which some people really hate](https://semitwist.com/articles/article/view/hg-fast-export-is-a-broken-piece-of-shit#comment-186)

Even when I finally managed to get it to find the mercurial module, it still doesn't work on my repo:

```
$ $HOME/Notes/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r $HOME/path-to-repo
Error: repository has at least one unnamed head: hg r194
git-fast-import statistics:
. . .
```

Producing nothing in the target git repo.

I tried hg-to-git in the git repo:

```
$HOME/Desktop/tmp/git-master/contrib/hg-to-git/hg-to-git.py -v .
tip is 1197
analysing the branches...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dsw/Desktop/tmp/git-master/contrib/hg-to-git/hg-to-git.py", line 135, in <module>
    hgchildren[parent] += ( str(cset), )
KeyError: '-1'
```

Maybe this is hg-to-git trying to tell me the same thing that hg-fast-export was telling me, only in a more visceral and gestalt way.  Somehow I think a tool should keep going in the face of an odd situation and produce at least a partial result, even if it informs the user of the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This problem has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58862418/208880).

Answer (score 0):

I've never wanted to do this, but I believe the easiest way is:

1. Install [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/)
2. Create an empty git repo somewhere
3. Go back to the hg repo
4. Create a bookmark called master, that points to your HEAD
5. hg push (git repo)

Basically, read the [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/) page. It's all there.