# at least one unnamed head error when converting mercurial repo to git using fast-export

Tags: git, mercurial, migrate

I am attempting to migrate from a mercurial repository to a git repository using [`fast-export`](https://github.com/frej/fast-export), but I am getting

> Error: repository has at least one unnamed head: hg r491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
The code below was enhanced by ondrej-stanek-ozobot and merged into `fast-export` on July 31, 2020.

---

**Original Answer**

I wrote a [plugin for `fast-export`](https://github.com/ethanfurman/fast-export.git) that allows you to specify the divergent commit for an unnamed head along with a new branch name, and that entire line will be moved to that new branch.

```
/path/to/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/hg_repo -f --plugin head2branch=aliases,373 --plugin head2branch=threads,374
```

Until this is (hopefully) merged, the steps to take to use this plugin:

```
git clone https://github.com/ethanfurman/fast-export.git
cd fast-export
git checkout head2branch-plugin
mkdir /path/to/new-git-repo
cd /path/to/new-git-repo
git init
/path/to/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/hg_repo
```

At this point, research each unnamed head to find its first divergent commit, and a new branch name for it.  For example:

```
$ /path/to/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r ~/path/to/hg-repo
Error: repository has unnamed head: hg r491
Error: repository has unnamed head: hg r373
```

Finally, run `fast-export` with the plugin active, specifying `-f` to ignore the unnamed heads error:

```
$ /path/to/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/hg-repo -f --plugin head2branch=aliases,373 --plugin head2branch=threads,374
```

Comment: `Does not work with pythone 3.8
What is head2branch=threads,374 ?`

Comment: @BillRichards: `threads` is the new name for that branch, `374` is the first diverging commit for that branch.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and found `hg-fast-export.sh` script has an option `--ignore-unnamed-heads` solving it